# C# Error in the regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I'm using C# 2012 and I can not solve this regular expression.

I need to validate the text so that points or traces are Mandatory to separate the numbers in the input text :
**[0-9]{9}(-|.)[\s]?[0-9]{4}(-|.)[0-9]{4}(-|.)0-9[0-9]{2}(-|.)[0-9]{4}**

A valid text should be as follows:
**0706570-39.2014.8.02.0001**

but the expression above returns true to the text below although it should be false:
**...Certidão de Casamento nº 00287301551
982200032250000901391 - Cartório Privativo....**

Comment: (-|.) is pointless because "**.**" already contains "**-**"

Comment: If you are looking for a dash or period between the numbers then you need to escape the period because a period will match anything.

Comment: It [does not match the input string](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5b0-9%5d%7b9%7d(-%7c.)%5b%5cs%5d%3f%5b0-9%5d%7b4%7d(-%7c.)%5b0-9%5d%7b4%7d(-%7c.)0-9%5b0-9%5d%7b2%7d(-%7c.)%5b0-9%5d%7b4%7d&i=00287301551982200032250000901). What input do you want to match?

Comment: text that should be located correctly:   0706570-39.2014.8.02.0001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^[0-9]{9}(-|\.)[\s]?[0-9]{4}(-|\.)[0-9]{4}(-|\.)0-9[0-9]{2}(-|\.)[0-9]{4}$
```

Add anchors `^...$` to denote start and end of string. Also escape `.`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the following regex:

```
\b[0-9]{7}[-.][0-9]{2}[-.][0-9]{4}[-.][0-9][.-][0-9]{2}[-.][0-9]{4}\b
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb%5b0-9%5d%7b7%7d%5b-.%5d%5b0-9%5d%7b2%7d%5b-.%5d%5b0-9%5d%7b4%7d%5b-.%5d%5b0-9%5d%5b.-%5d%5b0-9%5d%7b2%7d%5b-.%5d%5b0-9%5d%7b4%7d%5cb&i=0706570-39.2014.8.02.0001%0d%0a...Certid%c3%a3o+de+Casamento+n%c2%ba+00287301551+982200032250000901391+-+Cart%c3%b3rio+Privativo....)

If the expression must match individual full strings, replace `\b...\b` with `^...$`.

Note that `(-|.)` is really pointless as `.` matches `-`, so your intention was to match a literal `.`. To match  a literal `.`, you need to escape it (as vks shows), or put it into a character class `[.]`. A character class is a bit more efficient solution here since there is much less backtracking than with alternation `|` operator. Anyway, the original expression is matching different digit groups (see `[0-9]{7}(-|\.)\s?[0-9]{2}(-|\.)[0-9]{4}(-|\.)[0-9]{1}(-|\.)[0-9]{2}(-|\.)[0-9]{4}` just for a demo sake that is a "fixed" version.)